# jQuery - table & link detect show & hide

Tags: jquery

When I hover on the tr the block will show, but when mouse move to  tag the block will hidden.
How to do when hover the link or text,the block keep display?

**CSS**

```
.block{ display:none;width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#CCC;}
td{ border:1px solid #999;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Test1</a><div class="block">1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Test2</a><div class="block">2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Test3</a><div class="block">3</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Test4</a><div class="block">4</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Test5</a> && <strong>BoldText</strong><div class="block">5</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("tr").hover(function(){
             $(this).find(".block").show();
        });

        $("tr").mouseout(function(){
             $(this).find(".block").hide();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use both the in and out parts of the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler instead of [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) for the out handler.  The reason is that `mouseout` will trigger if the event target changes to the inner element, but you don't want that.

```
    $("tr").hover(function(){
         $(this).find(".block").show();
    }, function(){
         $(this).find(".block").hide();
    });
```

### [​See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWT7c/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
             $(this).parent().find(".block").show();
});
```

to your doc ready